# Can KeyFilter work through multiple levels?

Tags: autofac

I have a data access class that has its configuration data as a dependency.  I then have a "data consumer" class that has the data access class as its dependency.  I want to be able to select the configuration class in the constructor of the consumer.

I have this working in unit tests with the KeyFilter attribute.  However, it only works through one layer - I have to eliminate the middle data access class layer.  This doesn't work for my actual use case, but I believe it shows I'm using KeyFilter correctly.

Here is a test that passes:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ChooseCorrectlyThroughInterface()
    {
        var wrapper = new AutofacWrapper();

        wrapper.Register<ITest, Test1>();
        wrapper.Register<ITest, Test2>(UseTest2);
        wrapper.Register<IConsumer1, Consumer1>();
        wrapper.Register<IConsumer2, Consumer2>();

        using (wrapper.BeginScope())
        {
            var c1 = wrapper.Get<IConsumer1>();
            Assert.AreEqual("Test1", c1.ToString());

            var c2 = wrapper.Get<IConsumer2>();
            Assert.AreEqual("Test2", c2.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Consumer1's constructor looks like this:

```
    public Consumer1(ITest test)
```

but Consumer2 uses a KeyFilter:

```
    public Consumer2([KeyFilter(NamedBindingsShould.UseTest2)] ITest test)
```

My wrapper.Register method looks like this:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        Builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
            .As<TInterface>()
            .WithAttributeFiltering();
    }
    else
    {
        Builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
            .Named<TInterface>(name)
            .WithAttributeFiltering();
    }
```

This all works fine and the test passes.  However, the real use case is to add a layer between where the KeyFilter is defined on the constructor and the dependency that needs to vary.

I want to specify two different database config classes:

```
    wrapper.Register<IDatabaseConfigTest, DatabaseConfigDefault>();
    wrapper.Register<IDatabaseConfigTest, DatabaseConfigAlternate>(Alternate);
```

but only one data access class:

```
    wrapper.Register<IDatabaseTest, DatabaseTest>();
```

with this constructor:

```
    public DatabaseTest(IDatabaseConfigTest config)
```

and specify the KeyFilter in the data consumer class constructor:

```
    public DataConsumerDefault(IDatabaseTest database)

    public DataConsumerAlternate([KeyFilter(NamedBindingsShould.Alternate)] IDatabaseTest database)
```

I had this working in Ninject with a lot of kung fu (no pun intended), but I'm trying to switch to Autofac and I can't seem to get it to work.

Is this possible in Autofac?  Is there a different approach I can use besides KeyFilter?  I have a sample test project I can attach or send if needed.  I can also provide details as to how I did it in Ninject if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo...thanks to https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html?highlight=AttributedMetadataModule%20#option-3-use-keyed-services

I changed my wrapper.Register method to this:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            Builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
                .As<TInterface>()
                .WithAttributeFiltering();
        }
        else
        {
            Builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
                .Named<TInterface>(name)
                .WithParameter(
                    new ResolvedParameter(
                        (pi, ctx) => ctx.IsRegisteredWithName(name, pi.ParameterType),
                        (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed(name, pi.ParameterType)))
                .WithAttributeFiltering();
        }
```

and it worked!

Thank you documentation.